# LG V20 stucks on "firmware update, now looking for any connection" message

Tags: updates, lg, device-firmware

I powered off my LG V20 and 3 hours later went to turn it on and it says, "firmware update, now looking for any connection". It appears stuck on this screen. I can't do anything.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it myself. I held the button down for a while to try to turn it on.  Finally, the screen changed where I could toggle and select power off to stop the cycle.  It worked and the phone powered down.  I turned it back on and good to go.